# converting python file to exe file

Tags: python, excel, pdf, exe, tabula

i have a python file that converts pdf files to excel files from the same folder as the python file exists.
here is the code :

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader
from tabula.io import read_pdf

def pdf_to_excel(pdf_file):
    # Use PdfReader to open the PDF file
    with open(pdf_file, 'rb') as file:
        pdf_reader = PdfReader(file)
        
        # Initialize an empty list to store DataFrames
        all_tables = []
        
        # Iterate through pages and extract tables
        for page_number in range(len(pdf_reader.pages)):
            # Check if the page contains tables using tabula
            tables = read_pdf(pdf_file, pages=page_number+1, multiple_tables=True)
            
            # Convert each table to a DataFrame and append to the list
            for table in tables:
                df = pd.DataFrame(table)
                all_tables.append(df)
                
        # Concatenate all DataFrames into a single DataFrame
        final_df = pd.concat(all_tables, ignore_index=True)
        
        # Save the final DataFrame to a single Excel file
        excel_file = os.path.splitext(pdf_file)[0] + "_merged_tables.xlsx"
        final_df.to_excel(excel_file, index=False)
        print(f"All tables merged and saved to {excel_file}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Get the list of PDF files in the same folder
    pdf_files = [file for file in os.listdir() if file.lower().endswith('.pdf')]

    if not pdf_files:
        print("No PDF files found in the folder.")
    else:
        for pdf_file in pdf_files:
            pdf_to_excel(pdf_file)

input("Press Enter to exit...")
```

I have converted it to an exe file because the client hasn't python installed in his pc, so i used pyinstaller :
pip install pyinstaller
pyinstaller --onefile code.py
but when i ran the exe file it shows me an error :

```
Error importing jpype dependencies. Fallback to subprocess.
No module named 'technology'
Error from tabula-java:
Error: Unable to access jarfile C:\Users\achak\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI137762\tabula\tabula-1.0.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 40, in <module>
  File "code.py", line 17, in pdf_to_excel
  File "tabula\io.py", line 395, in read_pdf
  File "tabula\io.py", line 82, in _run
  File "tabula\backend.py", line 108, in call_tabula_java
  File "subprocess.py", line 571, in run
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['java', '-Dfile.encoding=UTF8', '-jar', 'C:\\Users\\achak\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI137762\\tabula\\tabula-1.0.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar', '--pages', '1', '--guess', '--format', 'JSON', 'file.pdf']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
[13140] Failed to execute script 'code' due to unhandled exception!
```

Comment: It looks like tabula is a Java utility, and pyinstaller is not sure how to bundle Python and Java and can't access `C:\Users\achak\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI137762\tabula\tabula-1.0.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar`